# O que é Trigger?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estava procurando sobre *triggers* neste site, mas não encontrei nenhuma pergunta sobre *triggers* e então:

- O que são *Triggers*?
- Quando usar uma *Trigger*?
- Como usar uma *Trigger*?
- Quais os usos e aplicabilidade das *Triggers*?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

Comment: Eu discordo! Essa pergunta " Diferença entre Triggers e Stored Procedures" fiz depois que perguntei: "O que é trigger?" e "O que são stored procedures?" . Aliás na pergunta: "O que são stored procedure?" não tem resposta e o @bigown marcou como ela como duplicata em relação a essa pergunta " Diferença entre Triggers e Stored Procedures?". Bem não vou marcar como "respondida" a resposta na pergunta " Diferença entre Triggers e Stored Procedures" do usuário bigown, porque ele não forneceu uma resposta completa e explicativa que nem da usuária Taisbevalle aqui nesta pergunta!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trigger, como o próprio nome diz é um `Gatilho`.

Você usa uma Trigger pra engatilhar uma função no banco de dados em determinado evento do banco, exemplo: `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE`.

Um uso comum de trigger é log de usuário, por exemplo, toda vez que for inserido um registro na tabela X, a trigger vai disparar um evento para uma função de log que vai pegar os dados desse `INSERT` e criar um log do usuário. Fazer log de versão, quando um usuário atualizar um registro a trigger dispara um evento para uma função de log que vai pegar os dados atuais do registro e os dados novos do `UPDATE` e criar um log falando o que foi alterado.

É comum ver aplicações legado com regra de negócio em procedure usando triggers pra executar a regra de negócio quando há um `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`.

Na minha opinião os usos e aplicabilidades de triggers depende de como você quer desenvolver a aplicação, se você não quer deixar certas responsabilidades com a aplicação e quer passar elas pro banco de dados.

Não vou por código aqui pois ja faz um bom tempo que não mexo com isso, mas de uma olhada nesse post http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-triggers/1695 , ele fala mais sobre trigger e quem sabe sane todas as suas dúvidas.

Answer (score 7):

**O que são Triggers?**

> Um trigger, ou gatilho, é um tipo especial de procedimento armazenado, que é executado sempre que há uma tentativa de modificar os dados de uma tabela que é protegida por ele.

(Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatilho_(banco_de_dados)))

**Quando usar uma *Trigger*?**

As *triggers* são utilizadas para fazer atualizações e exclusões em cascata. Uma confusão comum é achar que elas retornam resultados nas consultas, sendo que elas impõe e mantém a integridade referencial de baixo nível. Além disso, você pode usar *triggers* para definir mensagens de erro personalizadas, entre outras funcionalidades.

**Como usar uma *Trigger*?**

Para criar, alterar ou excluir um *trigger* são utilizadas as instruções [DML (*Data Manipulation Language*)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_manipula%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados). No site do [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ms189799.aspx), você encontra a sintaxe para a criação da *trigger*:

```
-- SQL Server Syntax  
Trigger on an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement to a table or view (DML Trigger)  

CREATE TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name   
ON { table | view }   
[ WITH <dml_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
{ FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF }   
{ [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] }   
[ WITH APPEND ]  
[ NOT FOR REPLICATION ]   
AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] | EXTERNAL NAME <method specifier [ ; ] }  

 <dml_trigger_option> ::=  
    [ ENCRYPTION ]  
    [ EXECUTE AS Clause ]  

 <method_specifier> ::=  
    assembly_name.class_name.method_name
```

Os argumentos são (tirado de [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173497.aspx)):

- `schema_name`: é o nome do esquema ao qual o gatilho DML pertence.
- `trigger_name`: identificará o *trigger* como objeto do banco de dados.
- `table | view`: tabela à qual o gatilho estará ligado, para ser disparado mediante ações de `insert`, `update` ou `delete`.
- Para definir o momento em que o *trigger* será disparado:

  - `FOR` é o valor padrão e faz com o que o gatilho seja disparado junto da ação.
  - `AFTER` faz com que o disparo se dê somente após a ação que o gerou ser concluída.
  - `INSTEAD OF` faz com que o *trigger* seja executado no lugar da ação que o gerou.
- `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`: uma ou várias dessas opções (separadas por vírgula) devem ser indicadas para informar ao banco qual é a ação que disparará o gatilho. Por exemplo, se o *trigger* deve ser disparado após toda inserção, deve-se utilizar `AFTER INSERT`.

Segundo o Rodrigo Almeida, no site [linha de código](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/611/triggers.aspx), algumas precauções sobre a implementação das *triggers* dentro do banco devem ser tomadas:

> - Use *triggers* para garantir a execução de comandos para uma tabela específica;
> - Não fique criando *triggers* que duplique regras já definidas em `CONSTRAINTS` do banco;
> - O Oracle recomenda que limitamos os nossos códigos no máximo em 60 linhas, caso você tenha que criar algo mais complexo crie `stored procedure`, será mais útil;
> - ATENÇÃO: Cuidado ao criar as *Triggers* que disparem sob uma instrução `UPDATE` na sua Tabela, não pode alterar a tabela porque
>     isso iria disparar a *Triggers* mais de `N` vezes no sistema, e a
>     memória do equipamento não iria aguentar ocasionando bugs de memória e
>     resultados errôneos.

**Quais os usos e aplicabilidade das *Triggers*?**

Alguns já foram ditos acima, porém existem outros diferentes propósitos para as *triggers*, entre eles podemos destacar:

> A geração de valores derivados de colunas da base de dados automaticamente, auditoria, replicação sincronizada de tabelas, prevenção de transações inválidas, aplicação de integridade referencial, imposição de autorização de segurança, registro de eventos e armazenamento de acesso as tabelas da base de dados.

(Fonte: [devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/triggers-pl-sql-saiba-quando-e-por-que-usar/30011))

Para entender a utilidade, imagine um banco de dados com muitos registros. Cada funcionário da empresa ganha por hora e você precisa atualizar o banco de horas de cada funcionário todos os dias. Quando criamos os *Triggers*, podemos definir o que deve ser mudado na tabela em um único arquivo e depois acionar um único comando DML, `update`, para ele, assim ele irá atualizar todos os registros de uma única vez.

Referências:

- [Introdução à triggers](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-triggers/1695)
- [Triggers](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/611/triggers.aspx)
- [Triggers - Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatilho_(banco_de_dados))
- [Triggers PL/SQL: saiba quando e por que usar](http://www.devmedia.com.br/triggers-pl-sql-saiba-quando-e-por-que-usar/30011)
- [Triggers no SQL Server: teoria e prática aplicada em uma situação real](http://www.devmedia.com.br/triggers-no-sql-server-teoria-e-pratica-aplicada-em-uma-situacao-real/28194)
- [Usando triggers](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/729/usando_triggers)
- [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ms189799.aspx)